# How can i create following soap header in WCF client

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-security, wcf-client, soapheader

I'm trying to call a web service in asp.net 4.0. Vendor has sent me the following sample soap header. I need to know how can i create following header in WCF client asp.net 4.0.

currently i'm using following code in app.config

```
<bindings>      
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="EDTPortBinding">
      <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11"/>
      <security 
            messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11"
            securityHeaderLayout="Strict"
            includeTimestamp="false"
            requireDerivedKeys="true"
            keyEntropyMode="ServerEntropy">
      </security>
      <httpsTransport authenticationScheme ="Negotiate" requireClientCertificate ="false" realm =""/>
    </binding>

  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

but i'm getting error 
Addressing Version 'AddressingNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)' does not support adding WS-Addressing headers. Following is a sample header which I need to generate from WCF client.

```
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-           200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-8B2ED84CAE64FADA2113775419342631">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
  <ds:Signature Id="SIG-6">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
 <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa soapenv"/>
 </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#TS-1">
 <ds:Transforms>
 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
 <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse erd edt abc deg soapenv"/>
 </ds:Transform>
   </ds:Transforms>
  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
 <ds:DigestValue>TSBdwFiHK6F64sibCXjThfekOJ5vQiXzPk5MjXPEwDE=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#UsernameToken-2">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="sdf edt dfs dfd soapenv"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>pFSgm8Pc531sbAN/Oo3glEbs1Rh741tXJya+70oALdo=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-3">
 <ds:Transforms>
 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dsf dfd sdf soapenv"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>FHoEV5Xp//KLgM1Fg5NyeIfkRjUramyx0Y0+kX41leg=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-4">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dsd edt dfd soapenv"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>2SieN++YDPYJwbhBTgirOvjJo0aQMwiTcg5bL4Oj0fU=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-5">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<ds:DigestValue>eALo7Pftw02ykaoXdlUt7IPiHB9RbRfj2t7zTLxzLXg=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>                       <ds:SignatureValue>lhXC6GdvAtJq87cQHin0DRkDWDMkKPUbyqEd1m5XRUz+puGxWIX8EtriEdCOQGf/fzmYg7Q5        qpbR xQYw94SCLHynJu1VCx7MoI8A3wFbwdsEKF9urE3rKzrM6F6YLlosuOiGNFN9kK20ryUAl4XHqCrC    C1Su3kFIiE0bwnWNCoi1bqt2zkomyBSVNXUOfw/QWfPbKlRZLNlzap1WPYK9ECSYF6Tf1g4R0lxk    7LcBYlWQn+P/qSIqZAv4jPDFQJS+pJ+3/Le8yEHNsZJfGjMKt2PF9jer3AJt+GqA3zQbj/5Ql0NF   AK/uZv25s2pji6cRcz29qeLlyqhYbzLgCTPlog==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-8B2ED84CAE64FADA2113775419343232">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-8B2ED84CAE64FADA2113775419343253">
<wsse:Reference URI="#X509-8B2ED84CAE64FADA2113775419342631"   ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-   1.0#X509v3"/>
 </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
 </ds:KeyInfo>
 </ds:Signature>
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2">
<wsse:Username>confsuxx@outlook.com</wsse:Username>
 <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-  token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxxxxxxxx</wsse:Password>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1">
<wsu:Created>2013-08-26T18:32:14Z</wsu:Created>
 <wsu:Expires>2013-08-26T18:32:44Z</wsu:Expires>
 </wsu:Timestamp>
 </wsse:Security>
<idp:IDP wsu:Id="id-4">
<ServiceUserMUID>039396</ServiceUserMUID>
 </idp:IDP>
 <ebs:EBS wsu:Id="id-3">
  <SoftwareConformanceKey>5cc6a261-d970-4898-920c-119fd07eads</SoftwareConformanceKey>
 <AuditId>444361ee-277f-7732-c684-7a9923jaaa1b</AuditId>
</ebs:EBS>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're using soap 1.1 with addressing, which is unusual.

Try setting the [textMessageEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731787.aspx) binding element :

```
<bindings>      
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="EDTPortBinding">
      ...
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
      ...
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll try that just wanna let you know that Vendor is using mtom protocol

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [See here](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/consuming-ebs-edt-soap-service-from-wcf.html) a detailed solution to consume this EBS-EDT service

You need both username and client certificate. This cannot be done via binding xml configuration. you must create the binding progrematically. Something like this:

```
        var b = new CustomBinding();

        var sec = (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10);
        sec.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());
        sec.MessageSecurityVersion =
            MessageSecurityVersion.
                WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;
        sec.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        sec.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.EncryptBeforeSign;

        b.Elements.Add(sec);
        b.Elements.Add(new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8));
        b.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());


        var c =
            new ServiceReference1.SimpleServiceSoapClient(b, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://www.url.com/"), new DnsEndpointIdentity("WSE2QuickStartServer"), new AddressHeaderCollection()));

        c.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "yaron";
        c.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "1234";

        c.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
            System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        c.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft WSE\v2.0\Samples\Sample Test Certificates\Server Public.cer");

        c.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft WSE\v2.0\Samples\Sample Test Certificates\Client Private.pfx", "wse2qs");

        c.EchoString("1");
```

Since you only use signature and not encryption you also need to set ProtectionLevel.Sign on your contract. See about this and other gotchas you may encounter in this [detailed wcf security post](http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2012/06/12-common-wcf-interop-confusions.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know how Can I create the certificate as I didn't receive any certificate from vendor.

Comment: you need to understand from the vendor what kind of client certificate they expect you to show. one option is to buy a certificate from an online vendor like verisign. another option is that they must give it to you since they only trust certificates they generate.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I went through the security specification document and they mentioned that

"To ensure confidentiality and integrity of sensitive information within the message,
sender software must use public key technology to sign the SOAP headers and body.
The signing certificate can be any available certificate and can be self signed."

Any idea?

Comment: it says you can use any certificate, so for testing you any certificate you may have, e.g. the ones linked here http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/axis2-wcf-interoperability.html. of course this is a strange statement by the vendor, if you use any certificate then they cannot know who you really are, there must be some way for you to eitehr tell them which certificate you will use or they must enforce some kind of regulation like specific issuers. Unless both client and server are deployed inside your organization and then it is your decision.

Comment: after providing your certificates i'm getting following error 
"The service certificate is not provided for target 'https://ws.astute.com:1441/EService/EService'. Specify a service certificate in ClientCredentials.". Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: make sure this line from my sample exists in your code and that it loads the server certificate (from my blog) c.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = ...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got rid of the above error. But now I'm getting this error "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail." And in inner exception it says "Internal error". Here is raw xml <?xml version="1.0"?>
-<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">-<env:Body>-<env:Fault><faultcode>env:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>

Comment: you need to compare the outgoing soap to the desired one. capture the outgoing with fiddler (or wcf logs - but make sure it is transport level message with security in it and not logical message with no security). you can publish it here.

Comment: I can't copy the xml here due to character limit so i publish the soap message as an answer. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: remember to add this so you only sign and not encrypt [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.SimpleServiceSoap", ProtectionLevel=System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)]

Comment: after changing protection level i'm getting this error "{"https://204.21.19.88:1441/Service/Service: cvc-simple-type 1: element username value 'conform142' is not a valid instance of type {http://hut.pharm.ont.com/}username"}"

Comment: this actually seems a progress - you have pass through the security hurdle and now there are schema differences. I suggest to first setup a working client to a version of the service that does not use security - and if you do not have one then mock a service that returns a fixed soap like the real service. this is to isolate this potential issues from the security issue

Comment: Currently it's creating request with default xmlns "<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">" But I need to generate like this "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:abc="http://abc.astute.ca/" xmlns:xyz="http://xyz.astute.ca/" xmlns:asd="http://asd.astute.ca/" xmlns:qwe="http://qwe.astute.ca/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">"
Any idea how can I customize it.

Comment: any idea on the above question. I really appreciate for you help. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Following is the soap message I captured from fiddler. This message is quite different from required message i published on top.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <k:EncryptedHeader a:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_3" xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <e:EncryptedData xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:Reference URI="#_0"></o:Reference>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
        <e:CipherData>
          <e:CipherValue>BB/K56PdPa2IXdceVcLvCmFIuly4HwOGVmv4OCI6sNd/D7pLzcz9R/DtCI7uKI7Xn1ppIzQf9P+HgQ6dB2k+Dc8SrKpbzgJR9JhTzOSxm/0ZkdVuk6nhpPORo0Ch4507u/YqaiQkveO/tANBXiToi9GgFNYEOZTzR/rMvpRmvEyGnlxOkiXQI8H5CJn87dZxMc/KITyaAae3CNFhcLcUIsMDgc58GICbjNCx09YLHuxHaofng+D1yGhW0CmtMymCvxcvLcZmvcH4QBMD1LeEmliqaVIA7PfrF0C6z4ukN7cK2lQyYPeiJ2HQ0Vd0MbaDYoX7qVt3c1SOlVEzGVhC1NDi7Ejilt6laftyqX2uBWd0JcLsJpLLYioTB5mcxuXS+0LnmAGuU6njJWEfTqidLyticIzo3yitFdgjofgaGymkjVq0jCtTfE8mkzLTW2/S</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
      </e:EncryptedData>
    </k:EncryptedHeader>
    <k:EncryptedHeader a:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4" xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <e:EncryptedData xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:Reference URI="#_0"></o:Reference>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
        <e:CipherData>
          <e:CipherValue>pFKhSf01843H0S0lR16/NFymFGqVt6cNNP2VzL8W6t8N+4uVI3QAMj0NigFigBpNi1WtXLV/Y5E3zUlnEP6drl1pVWo7ue4fYIKM3VZ347p27xHLO72Jy+734uf9n8nI1ruiWGPZZ/hDUwB5gmU0AEJGJPDzKS4fd3fZcMKaem7I9g8nRNhEE5sBq7w2YraIRsep++MK7FSqNJ/y6RIw5ifaVtEIzMqiXdPv6DSpfkU=</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
      </e:EncryptedData>
    </k:EncryptedHeader>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="8d7e0216-f29e-466d-8f59-fee9237be43a" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">30b8fade-6c73-4e77-aff7-98248cea2c09</ActivityId>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo1UOM+fT2PVBuVeE+3YdGt4AAAAAm+k0MQFSMkSxuNClyxbltwINs5gG8f1OoEvHXvwJM9IACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-14ace37f-2548-40e3-b88a-f3d95a3fef73-1">
        <u:Created>2013-09-09T02:07:20.028Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2013-09-09T02:12:20.028Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
      <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-03555e25-2fe1-4dcf-bbda-42727af2e12f-3" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">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</o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
          <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
        </e:EncryptionMethod>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <X509Data>
              <X509IssuerSerial>
                <X509IssuerName>CN=EMRAN-PC</X509IssuerName>
                <X509SerialNumber>83168549829936402630366527231323642802</X509SerialNumber>
              </X509IssuerSerial>
            </X509Data>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
        <e:CipherData>
          <e:CipherValue>JBPf96uwqg3QWqWrqBXLms269TvxNiPuwQiIp1yCxpFCmGYlHAPPzwKp0uIaY2GotNeot9eg29ob5hu9KAYUiYPHklVXYbl4pg3Jvim4O6ElcbkN5A6v1eTZgk7xLlDf+eMGT7zCP0UwjEjzl8Z/K9VdLSASV9E7eUHiZH2xQmbuhyckQAEGSzlpFO3pu9fiTTQZRScURc6cn6hCTsNaLT93nJUWKY2rSehDWA5X8WBMVs5E2nYxBdXzmRABP/0nW8BGRyKvl9reqxB/3nmCErG5ADLI2XlipT4h/pa6o7qYMHaiPPYTOuM+3dXdGie2gYv89j5TIQfeaRMiyFuqyA==</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
      </e:EncryptedKey>
      <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-03555e25-2fe1-4dcf-bbda-42727af2e12f-1">
        <o:Username>abcdf14</o:Username>
        <o:Password>asdfasdf34!</o:Password>
      </o:UsernameToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#_2">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>cnhQbioITPIFIdQJYIuRoxIZcKs=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#_3">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>tY4Bfb76si198z7okwNeD2AqChg=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#_4">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>zAqp1Yf2HzJ12a2WQZj6ZsvN44M=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#uuid-14ace37f-2548-40e3-b88a-f3d95a3fef73-1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>4F0ElIwHLQe4hnmTCqxo7n8Q/U4=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#uuid-03555e25-2fe1-4dcf-bbda-42727af2e12f-1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>0u8ZWlKe7AGzrNJDS+ytvn1Jumg=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>jnxPBBQEUNYPL8OcrzSywUVa/ipMwLiKlE+n+W7EpgKZjz2LJlCF8BYEJ4yOrF4WsiX1k26qSk/O59Kf+PWRqhJGYQ2Z0eZc5CW4upHhHoatymKFLphh75d4xef7dfPs+MvsN5Elw2QHvsiz5uO7OLyP5uSCNdVxg9F3zjcfmnW4aIIHvzV8PmTpysmPAnoNvRkNjGFxuemLERVKxjWc1Rn8JDy6nDVi4wYvISn1d6i00IsrIc0LJZosx/MwuSiE8AOP6Lo6+1eBDUzd6S9vqN6fCcJ1lykO6CouMuo+qxA37nmItfsgb7NtC+lAZpnVRB9qC8aqaFsXh9Vu1qeUoA==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <o:Reference URI="#uuid-03555e25-2fe1-4dcf-bbda-42727af2e12f-3"/>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
      <e:ReferenceList xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:DataReference URI="#_1"/>
        <e:DataReference URI="#_3"/>
        <e:DataReference URI="#_4"/>
      </e:ReferenceList>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body u:Id="_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <e:EncryptedData Id="_1" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
          <o:Reference URI="#_0"></o:Reference>
        </o:SecurityTokenReference>
      </KeyInfo>
      <e:CipherData>
        <e:CipherValue>t52vr+BDePvaT3bRjdKNt1Py915Jn/x7XAtM+z2c9I6nlFhw/Sf6H4AQh+MpRolfzoBIcmZQWQ56x6YrhdbOEVI9s+zEprLcvBoGn1JewZ1U7rqdpjXVuiee83hMHeFTT2THIJ7fX1O7Pm3rWxqM0AMaUm41UACnaxp0hZAncCFPEoc/+AtyC39zS/oxKYchNzVDkEBkoxjDnHndrQt2XGVSV0fjnCnWfAZ1Zi2zXVH50RA7nTSufZjZXld78nphJ+a5QqeT9V9XGWsd7Pg2ivI9ykb7Ke5IMTYD4nmLV7zR+zqMDiQnj+7GEpVKnuCraOilkr8afwyWZF97vi+9A1PIvzJbKnlQ3jryDZDUmWU=</e:CipherValue>
      </e:CipherData>
    </e:EncryptedData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```